# Bootstrap Video Carousel Doesn't Work on Mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video, mobile, carousel

I'm able to get the video playing on desktop but not on mobile devices.  Is this possible?  Do I need to use an image placeholder?

I used code from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/video-carousel/ but could not get video playing on mobile browsers.

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="home-inner">
  <div class="on-the-fly-behavior">
  
    <!-- /.myCarosel -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" style='overflow:hidden;'>
    
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      </ol>
      
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <video class="img-fluid" autoplay loop muted class="myvid" id="player" style="width:100%;">
            <source src="videos/6691_SALTWME_720.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
           Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
          </video>
        </div>
        
        <div class="item">
          <a href="/cgi-bin/livew/wam_tmpl/catalog_browse.p?site=B2B&layout=BaseB2B&page=catalog_browse&searchText=melange"><img src="{{GLOBAL_imageurl}}home/MelangeWindow.jpg" alt="LAT Apparel:  Melange 3379"></a>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="item">
          <a href="/product/3321/TODDLER-FINE-JERSEY-TEE.html"><img src="{{GLOBAL_imageurl}}home/LAT-apparel-3321-toddler-fine-jersey-tee.jpg" alt="LAT Apparel Pattern Prints:  3321"></a>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="item">
          <a href="/product/3339/TODDLER-GIRLS-FLUTTER-SLEEVE-T.html"><img src="{{GLOBAL_imageurl}}home/LAT-apparel-3339-flutter-sleeve-tee.jpg" alt="LAT Apparel Flutter Sleeve Tee:  3339"></a>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
      <!-- /.carousel--inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.myCarosel -->
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.